# Wrong pgp key was signed

Tags: digital-signature, pgp, gnupg, web-of-trust

Someone signed my PGP key, by accident (we have never met, but I know the person a little).

The wrong signature was uploaded to the SKS pool.
Is there anything we can do about it to improve the web of trust again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They can revoke the signature using the revsig command of `gpg --edit-key` then re-upload the key to the keyservers.  Alternatively you could meet up with them demonstrate your bona fides and make the signature retroactively true.